# XMPP (SMACK API) how to save login session?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am using Smack API to connect to the Openfire server from Android application. At the first time I have successfully made it work to login user and send message to other user. But my problem is when i remove the app from the stack and try to connect with the server again then connection was established but it also requires login again to send or receive message. So how can i manage login session so that i don't need to login again?

Answer (score 0):

openfire by default remove the sessions of the idle clients. To achieve what you are asking, you have to overwrite `xmpp.client.idle` in your openfire  to `-1` to make your session continues.

but i would recommend you otherwise because it may result in possible loss of message.but you can always increase your session time from default to your preference